# MongoDB: $nin and $in not working together in $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have below documents in my `transactions` collections.

```
{txnId: 1, amount: 200, tags:["monthly", "recharge"]},
{txnId: 2, amount: 4000, tags:["monthly", "salary"]},
{txnId: 3, amount: 1000, tags:["monthly", "waterbill"]},
{txnId: 4, amount: 400, tags:["monthly", "electricity"]},
{txnId: 5, amount: 300, tags:["dinner", "daily"]}
```

I want to fetch all the documents which are having **monthly** but not ***salary***

Some queries I tried and their respective outputs:

**Query 1:**

```
db.transactions.find({tags: {$elemMatch: {$in: ["monthly"], $nin: ["salary"]}}})
```

**Output 1:**

```
{txnId: 1, amount: 200, tags:["monthly", "recharge"]}
{txnId: 2, amount: 4000, tags:["monthly", "salary"]}
{txnId: 3, amount: 1000, tags:["monthly", "waterbill"]}
{txnId: 4, amount: 400, tags:["monthly", "electricity"]}
```

**Query 2:**

```
db.transactions.find({tags: {$nin: ["salary"]}})
```

**Output 2:**

```
{txnId: 1, amount: 200, tags:["monthly", "recharge"]}
{txnId: 3, amount: 1000, tags:["monthly", "waterbill"]}
{txnId: 4, amount: 400, tags:["monthly", "electricity"]}
{txnId: 5, amount: 300, tags:["dinner", "daily"]}
```

**Query 3:**

```
db.transactions.find({tags: {$nin: ["salary"]}, tags: {$elemMatch: {$in: ["monthly"]}}})
```

**Output 3:**

```
{txnId: 1, amount: 200, tags:["monthly", "recharge"]}
{txnId: 2, amount: 4000, tags:["monthly", "salary"]}
{txnId: 3, amount: 1000, tags:["monthly", "waterbill"]}
{txnId: 4, amount: 400, tags:["monthly", "electricity"]}
```

Why **$in** and **$nin** not working together, and even $nin not working as expected ? or did I misunderstand ?

Comment: I too tried your queries and still not able to justify how `$nin` and `$in` working together. But the below query helped me to achieve the expected result `db.test.find({"$and": [{tags: "monthly"}, {tags: {$ne: "salary"}}]})`

Comment: let me know if the above query helps you for now. Anyway, the working of $nin and $in together is still open!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $nin & $in together too. The below query will give the expected records. Hope need not use $elemMatch.

```
db.transactions.find({$and:[{tags:{$in:['monthly']}}, {tags:{$nin:['salary']}}]}).toArray()
```

**Output:**

```
[
{txnId: 1, amount: 200, tags:["monthly", "recharge"]},
{txnId: 3, amount: 1000, tags:["monthly", "waterbill"]},
{txnId: 4, amount: 400, tags:["monthly", "electricity"]}
]
```